# Tomcat6 doesn't seem to load my LogFormatter class

Tags: java, logging, tomcat6, classloader, java.util.logging

I want to customize my log messages in Tomcat6, and have created a class "MyFormatter" which looks like this:

```
public class LogFormatter extends Formatter {

@Override
public String format(LogRecord record) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("LOLCAT--")
            .append(new Date(record.getMillis()))
            .append(" \t")
            .append(record.getThreadID())
            .append(" \t")
            .append(record.getSourceMethodName())
            .append(" \t")
            .append(record.getSourceClassName())
            .append(" \t")
            .append(record.getLevel().getLocalizedName())
            .append(": ")
            .append(formatMessage(record))
            .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I've packed this into a .jar and placed in ${catalina.home}/lib.

In my logging.properties file I've added the following:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = lolcat.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = my.package.LogFormatter
```

After sevral attempts trying different packaging, different configs, i decided to try the built in "org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter" - and this works perfectly. So the config should be fine.

The question remains, why doesn't Tomcat6 load my class?

Comment: What error are you seeing ? Do you know if it *can* load it or if this is merely a config issue ?

Comment: The log doesn't say anything about this at all, it just falls back to the default log format. I think I've read that it does this fallback silently.

Comment: properties file says it should be in the my.package is it so? as class doesn't have any package there

Comment: `package my.package;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;`

This is the top part which i left out.

The jar is also packed with folder structure /my/package/LogFormatter.class

Comment: I got this to work by adding the .jar to "...\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\lib\ext". 

This is probably because this folder is loaded before any other Tomcat stuff. However it's probably not the best place to keep it in a production environment. Is there any other folders/configurations I can do to keep it inside the tomcat folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

After reading about Tomcat and Class Loading, i found that there is an order which Tomcat follows. It goes like this;

Bootstrap (/jre/lib/ext) -> System (/catalina-home/bin/) -> Common (/catalina-home/lib) -> Webapps.

tomcat-juli.jar which contains the logging stuff is loaded with the "System"-step, so when you place other logging stuff in common, it ignores it cause its already loaded.

The solution is then to place the .jar before tomcat-juli.jar is loaded aka in /jre/lib/ext.´

Edit:
It's not always a great idea to keep it in the jre folder, so I found that the best solution is to put it in an endorsed directory.

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${catalina_home}/endorsed
```

This endorsed directory will run before **System** class loading.